# exponent pow function returns wrong ASCII total

Tags: c++, algorithm, ascii, pow

I am doing a function that turns a string into a number encoded as base 31. For example,

```
"cat"  =>  'c' * 31^(3-1) + 'a' * 31^(3-2) + 't'  = 67510
```

My code prints out as follows:

```
Enter text to convert to ASCII: cat
ASCII : 99
ASCII : 97
ASCII : 116
ASCII total: 312
Each ASCII in algorithm : 95139
Each ASCII in algorithm : 98146
Each ASCII in algorithm : 98146
Total ASCII algorithm : 98262
```

In other words:

```
'c' should be 95139
'a' should be 3007
't' should be 116
```

I believe the issue is found within my pow function but from the examples I have referenced, the set up that I have should work. I can't seem to determine what is causing the issue and wanted to see if a second pair of eyes could help me see the problem.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void ToASCII(string letter)
{
    int total =0;
    int length = 0;
    int increment = 1;
    int num =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length(); i++)
    {
        char x = letter.at(i);
        cout <<"ASCII : "<< int(x) << endl;
        total = total + x;
        length++;
    }
    cout <<"ASCII total: "<< total << endl;
    int code = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++){

        num += int(letter.at(j))* pow(31,(length-increment));
        cout <<"Each ASCII in algorithm : " << num <<endl;
        increment++;
    }
    cout <<"Total ASCII algorithm : " << num<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    string Text;
    cout << "Enter text to convert to ASCII: ";
    getline(cin, Text);
    ToASCII(Text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(length+increment)` have `-` instead of `+` ?

Comment: @Kolmar yes I just caught that once I posted so i corrected that. However, the assci values are still wrong. value 'a' for cat should be '3007'

Comment: cat -> 67510 doesn't make sense if c should be 95139

Comment: You are printing `num` which is the sum of all previous values, so for `a` the program is actually printing the sum of values for `a` and `c`

Comment: @rpattiso you are correct. I was informed the wrong amount of 67510 to be the correct answer. So my final answer is correct in the end but my adding up to it when displayed separately isn't. Thanks for clarification. That means my final amount is correct.

Comment: Normally, when you talk about base b, the digits are 0 through b-1. You are allowing digits from int('a')=97 up, maybe through int('z') if you are only entering lowercase words with no punctuation. It is more common to subtract int('a') from the value for each letter.